# Google Calendar Import or Copy All Entries From a WebCal:// URL

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, synchronization, import

I have a webcal:// url for a calendar with a lot of entries, I can "add" the calendar in the "other calendars" section of my Google Calendar.

But this isn't part of my calendar so will not sync with other devices that are linked to the account.

Is there a way to copy/import ALL these entries inside Google calendar, without doing them one at a time via the "copy to my calendar" option on each entry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by clicking "Add | Add by URL" at the bottom of the left nav on your google calendar homepage.

[image: Adding an iCal to Google Calendar]
**Figure: Adding an iCal to sync is as easy as adding the URL**

You will be asked to choose to sync with your main calendar or a new named one, but if you stick it in the main calendar you should then get it on your other devices.

Comment: This is no longer correct: Adding by URL now always adds a subscription to the given calendar as a separate calendar.