# How do I allow web calendar links for Google Calendar on Windows 10 MS Edge?

Tags: google-calendar, windows-10, microsoft-edge

On Windows 10, using Microsoft Edge, Google Calendar asks me to allow it to open web calendar links.

Occasionally, Google Calendar pops a pop-up message asking me to let it open web calendar links. I did a thorough search and tried the suggested solutions. Some of them were relevant to Chrome and some to Windows 11. Found nothing for the Windows 10 / Edge combination.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do Google Calendar asks you to allow it to open web calendar links? Please search this site and the MS Edge and Google Calendar resources for end users thoroughly, share what you tried and what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. Ref [ask].

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR:

The dialog is a standard feature of some modern web browsers. It's related to the web browser setting Protocol Handler. This is responding to a check done by Google Calendar. This is not shown all the time because the default option might be to ignore it or the app use an algorithm to not be too anonying. The details about how Google Calendar internally works are beyond the scope of Web Applications.

## Review the Protocol Handler settings

### Microsoft Edge

In Microsoft Edge go to

`edge://settings/content/handlers?search=protocol%20handlers`

Or click the Settings button then type "protocol handlers" in the search box.

This is my setup:

- Microft Edge for Mac Version 111.0.1661.54 (Official build) (arm64)
- MacOS Ventura  13.2.1

In my case the above link takes me to a screen that looks as follow:

[image: Protocol Handler]

---

Snapshoots showing how the Microsft Edge toolbar looks when opening Google Calendar:

[image: Microsoft Edge for Mac Toolbar - Google Calendar]

When clicking in the [image: protocols handler] (protocols handler) button, the following dialog is opened:

[image: Allow calendar.google.com to open all web calendar links]

---

### Google Chrome

In Microsoft Chrome go to

`chrome://settings/handlers`

Or click the three dots button, then Settings.
In the search box type Handlers.
Click in Additional Permissions > Protocol Handlers

I'm using

- Chrome Version 111.0.5563.110 (Official Build) (arm64)

This is what is shown to me:

[image: Chrome Protocol Handlers]

### Firefox

Firefox handle the protocol handlers differently than Microsoft Edge and Chrome. It will be necessary to make use of a small script.

1. Copy th following script

   ```
   window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("webcal", "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?cid=%s", "Google Calendar");
   ```
2. In Firefox, go to https://calendar.google.com.
   [image: Firefox - Google Calendar]
3. Open the web browser console. If your keyboard functions keys press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the web developer tools. In Mac press <kbd>Command+Opt</kbd>+I
   [image: Web console]
4. Paste the script. You might be warned to not fun scripts from strangers and might be required to type `allow paste`.
5. Click **Run**
6. A bar will be shown in the top of the web page asking to confirm to add Google Calendar as an application to open webcal files. Click **Add application**.
   [image: Confirm calendar.google.com as application of webcal links -> Add application]

Then in Firefox > Settings > Applications, you can manage the application to be used to handle webcal links.

[image: Settings - Applications]

## Notes

You might be seeing a dialog from a old version or maybe the differences of what each other are seeing are due to the operative system, anyway that is not really important, but just in case as
a good practice regularly verify that your operative system has installed all the critical updates and that your web browser is automatically updated.

## Related

### Web Applications

- [Google Calendar Import or Copy All Entries From a WebCal:// URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6009/88163)
- [Google Calendar not showing updated entries from iCal URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46297/88163)

### Super User

- [Automatically open ICS files in Google Calendar](https://superuser.com/q/44191/152004)

## References

- [Web-based protocol handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers)
- [Navigator.registerProtocolHandler()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler#browser_compatibility)
- [How can I get Firfox to open webcal links (webcal://website.org/ical/appointments.ics) with Google calendar?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1196085)

Comment: I have done it for the webcal protocol, but what about webcals protocol? It doesn't let me add it for that. Gives a permission denied error